# Is a ISO C90 compiler needed for install gcc

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, iso, c89

for installing gcc, one of the prerequisites is ISO C90 compiler for bootstrapping gcc, as per this link http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html

I have searched web and could not find any such thing ' ISO C90 compiler' . what exactly the website is refering to?

Comment: The prerequisite you refer to is required for *building* gcc, not for installing it. It also mentions a binary for an existing gcc compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That applies only if you're building gcc from source.  On most systems, it's much easier to install a binary distribution, which doesn't require an existing C compiler (because whoever created the binary distribution used a C compiler to compile gcc for you, or got the binaries from someone else who did).

C90 is the 1990 version of the ISO C standard.  Since gcc is implemented in C, you need an existing C compiler to build it.  This can be an earlier version of gcc, for example.  If you tell us what operating system you're using, we can give you a better idea where to find a C compiler you can install.

As for the "ISO C90" requirement, just about any C compiler you're likely to find will support ISO C90 at least well enough to bootstrap gcc.  The phrase "ISO C90 compiler" is very nearly equivalent to "C compiler".  (Only some very old C compilers will fail to support C90.)

Comment: I have had a fresh installation of fedora 16 on my computer. now I wanted to install gcc so that I could compile some c programs. i applied yum install gcc and its all done.. It means some c compiler was already there. isn't it? Out of curosity I want to know if all operating systems come with some basic ISO C90 compiler.

Comment: No, you just installed a binary (precompiled) version of gcc.  Your computer downloaded the appropriate binary packages and installed the executables, libraries, and other files that make up gcc.  The system on which the binary packages were created must have had a C compiler installed, and used it to build gcc from source (that system is probably one owned by Red Hat).

Comment: aha... I installed a binary, therefore i didn't require a c compiler.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The compiler on you OS is most likely already C90 compliant unless is is very old (ie you OS is pre 1990). Just go ahead and try building gcc.

Look for a version of gcc already built by your OS provider.

Comment: That's assuming the system has a C compiler already installed.  Many systems these days don't.

Comment: I would argue the other way :-) only winblowz doesnt have a compiler easily available. Although not sure if the OP wants to install gcc or build it.

Comment: There's a difference between "easily available" and "pre-installed".  I believe there are Unix-like systems that don't install a C compiler by default (though it's typically a one-line command to download and install one).

Comment: @Keith. Agree - yes - its probably not installed by default.

Comment: It appears that Fedora 16 is one such system.

Comment: dammit - Fedora just released that already - just manged to tolerate FC15 :-) - but hey they released on my birthday ;-)

Comment: and I have 46Gb of local repos for FC15 too :-( dammit - more downloads from work needed